# Does Task.Run guarantee each method will be run to completion

Tags: c#-4.0, async-await, task-parallel-library

There are two methods that together ***must*** be run in parallel, this is due to a time constraint. The next piece of data to work on is coming every 100ms for example.

```
 List<Widget> widgetList = new List<Widget>() 
 {
     file list with 100 widget objects
 }
 List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

 foreach (Widget widget in widgetList)
 {
    Task t = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
       var result = await widget.Analyze(newData);
       ReportResults(result);
    });
    tasks.Add(t);
  }
  Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

No it is not a complete code example but should be enough for the question which is as follows:
Can I be sure that ReportResults(result) will run to completion per Task or is it possible that if a Task finishes and calls ReportResults(result) and then another task finishes that it can call ReportResults(result) resulting in unpredictable behavior?

TIA,
Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each method will run to completion, unless something tears down the process or application domain.

As the "call ReportResults(result) resulting in unpredictable behavior", it depends on how `ReportResults` works.

I would do something like this instead:

```
var results = await Task.WhenAll(
    for widget in widgetList
    select widget.Analyze(newData));

foreach (var result in results)
{
    ReportResults(result);
}
```

**Note:** `async-await` is a C# 5.0 feature, not available in C# 4.0.

Comment: Good suggestion! As it turns out you are correct, as long as nothing tears things down the do run to completion. I think you solution is a bit more elegant.